# Reusable Logo path in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, svg, png

I am new in photoshop so I try to describe what I need to solve.

I drew logo which composed of 2 layers and each layer is of different color. This logo I created in workspace which has big resolution (about 3000px x 1500px). When I export this image as PNG, I also need smaller version of it for site. So I resized it, and whole logo start being pixelated. I tried to solve it with pats. I made paths of each layer, then create vector mask, and export it as SVG. Then I tried it add to smaller workspace (300px x 150px) and export it as smaller png but I was unsuccessful. Added svg is pixelated as well.

When I added svg to new project it added as new layers which looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Also I lost information about layers when I want change colors, because it was added as I layer. Can you please tell me how to solve this properly? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to GDSE. You appear to have zoomed in on a raster image. You can't do that and not expect to see pixels. Instead view the raster image at 100% (1:1).  Don't ever zoom in on raster images.

Comment: @BillyKerr I dont think is real problem, logo looks blured and not sharp when I am not zoomed in as well

Comment: Do you have some system zoom set up in your computer display settings?  With system zoom set, images viewed in a browser will be zoomed in. Check your display settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not expect smooth and razor sharp curves when your raster image is only 150 pixels high. You get this, no matter the shapes are vectors in Photoshop:

[image]

Photoshop renders finally vector shapes to the base image pixel resolution. Depending on the antialias settings it's either jagged or blurry or something between. It looks acceptable only if you have it on the screen as 150 screen pixels high:

[image]

Your SVG can be a low resolution bitmap image packed to SVG format. Check is it a vector in Illustrator or Inkscape. If you read XML language open it in a text editor.

Comment: thank you for response